# Problems with input through JS prompt

Tags: javascript

I am doing a lab on JS as a beginner for a uni assignment and the task is to: 
"Once the page is loaded, it asks for user’s name.
1.1. Asking for user’s name is skipped, if this has been already entered by user. The user’s name is stored
per session in a cookie and in Web storage (for a session); both must be implemented.
1.2. User can provide his/her name either through a form, or JS prompt.
1.3. The user name is shown on top of the page as “User’s shopping list” (e.g. Fig.1 John’s Shopping list)."
My code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title id="g"> </title>
 <script>
  function name_inp() {
      if (!name_input) {
        var name_input = prompt("Please enter your name");
    console.log(name_input);
    sessionStorage.setItem(name_input);
        document.cookie = name_input;
    document.getElementById("g").innerHTML = name_input + "'s Shopping List";
      }
   if (name_input != null) {
    document.getElementById("g").innerHTML = name_input + "'s Shopping List";
   }
  }
 </script>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;" onload="name_inp()">
 <h1 id="g"></h1>
  <form action="index.html" method="post">
  <label>Product 1</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="1stprod"><br>
  <label>Amount</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="1stnum"><br>
  <label>Product 2</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="2ndprod"><br>
   <label>Amount</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="2ndnum"><br>
  <label>Product 3</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="3rdprod"><br>
   <label>Amount</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="3rdnum"><br>
   <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

And the thing is that it doesn't save the cookies anywhere, for which I cannot find a reason why. CAn anyone point me into the right direction? (note: JS beginner, so an in-depth explanation would help a looot)

Comment: You must read the documentation first.`sessionStorage.setItem` takes two parameters, one for the key and one for the value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: Also, read the documentation on handling cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie. Cookies must also have key and value: `document.cookie = "username=john";`.